# Hide all Wordpress elements except Woocommerce products page?

Tags: woocommerce

I need to only see on the home page in my wordpress installation the woocommerce product pages.
No menus, no headers, nothing at all.

How can i do this?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Using theme StoreFront and StoreFront PowerPack i can hide all components i want.